# How to console.log a big and colored text in the console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm quite new to javascript, HTML... I've learned quite enough with HTML but don't understand js as much (a little basics)I want to tell some info in the console to the person that goes to the console on my site, I know you obviously have to console.log in but I want to design it like discord, if you go to https://discordapp.com/ and go to the console you can see something like what is in this picture

[image: this picture]

how would I do that?

```
console.log("Some text to be displayed in the console");
```

Comment: You can click *line number* on the right side of that dev tool window to check the actual code :)

Comment: I know i can but it takes long to openup the js file, it's kinda big for my pc it lags rip

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
console.log("%c" + "Hold Up!", "color: #7289DA; -webkit-text-stroke: 2px black; font-size: 72px; font-weight: bold;");
```

Regards